# OAuth2 - Can it be used for signing in securely without 3rd party?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0

This may sound like a dumb question or the title is too general, but the reason I am asking it is because I want to create a secure login system on my website that will be accessed by web applications to access our services. (Plus I am asking this question before I spend 20 days of research before finding out it's not what I am looking for.)

But every time I search OAuth2, it is usually just about "It allows FB to connect on your behalf, or uses your Google account signin somewhere else securely".

So my question is, is OAuth2 a good fit for my C++ application to securely sign in on my own website and operate on said API securely? (TLS is already being used.)

Answer (score 2):

Good question and the answer is: "no". You need an extension of OAuth 2.0 to sign on users to websites. See: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 can be used to authorize your api's if you are federating your website with say Google/Facebook and want authentication to be done by them. Once the user is an authenticated Google/Facebook user and if you deem them to be fine, you could allow access to your api's based on the token received. However, this is a very subjective question and depends on what kind of security model you want in your website.